# How to view active query underlying cursor

Tags: postgresql

In `pg_stat_activity` I can see that a client is working its way through some query results using a cursor. But how can I see what the original query is?

```
pipeline=> select pid, query from pg_stat_activity where state = 'active' order by query_start;
  pid  |                                                         query
-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  6734 | FETCH FORWARD 1000 FROM "c_109886590_1"
 26731 | select pid, query from pg_stat_activity where state = 'active' order by query_start;
(2 rows)
```

I see there is `pg_cursors`, but it is empty:

```
pipeline=> select * from pg_cursors;
 name | statement | is_holdable | is_binary | is_scrollable | creation_time
------+-----------+-------------+-----------+---------------+---------------
(0 rows)
```

The server is on AWS RDS.

```
pipeline=> select version();
                                                   version
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.3.3 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't.

`pg_cursors` is backend-local. It doesn't show cursors that aren't part of the current connection.

PostgreSQL has no way to find out what query underlies a cursor from another session.

The only way I can think of to do this is using log analysis, with `log_statement = all` and a suitable `log_line_prefix`.