# logging "declare csr cursor for " statement

Tags: postgresql, logging

I need to find longtime query in pg 9.4.5 server.

with `log_min_duration_statement = '10s'`

I get  long fetch like :

```
 LOG:  duration: 177667.288 ms  statement: fetch curs_foo
```

Unfortunately, declaring a cursor is faster than 10s and is never written in the log.

I need to get the statement used, is there a way to write

`"LOG:  statement: declare curs_foo cursor for  SELECT ...."`

only with a tips in postgresql.conf  ?

- Most of my code is pgc and cannot be changed
- most of this pgc code builds the query on the fly with many many many ways to make the used statement
- logging all statement is not an option

Comment: Try if you can see definition in pg_cursors - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-cursors.html - maybe you would have to read it repeatedly from OS and store results

Comment: This was a good idea, but even while a fetch is running in pg_stat_activity, pg_cursors remains empty :-(

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516407/how-to-view-active-query-underlying-cursor 
pg_cursors is linked to session, ... fail

Comment: yes, unfortunately you are right - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131348/see-the-definition-of-a-cursor - pitty documentation does not tell it...

Comment: If you're logging to syslog, you could tell Postgres to log everything, and use a syslog filter to throw most of it away. Not very nice, but I don't have any better ideas...